# Storing .RDS files in a github repository

Tags: r, gitlab, rdata

Once upon a time I got in trouble with IT for pushing binary files (encrypted archives) to my employer's GitLab; the files were large, and after a short while we ran out of storage space... my bad.

At the moment I'm doing the same thing with temporary .RDS files. I'll eventually move the data to a more suitable storage option, but that's not a priority at this point. My question: is it OK to track .RDS files in git repositories, or will I end up devouring too much storage space? The files are tiny, but over time there might be a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, these files are temporary. Only if they are very time consuming to regenerate, should they be tracked. And your .rds files can be regenerated from the code, right?

Comment: yeah, but some of the scripts take a few minutes to run which is why I opted for the temporary .RDS approach. On the other hand, the files rarely change after I've saved them; only when I discover mistakes.